# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when I run my script (oracle 19c)

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have newly installed oracle 19C for the first time and wanted to try it out. We have a java project where we have inside some scripts which are used to create users, upgrade users.. etc. When I run this script I get The error ORA-01031: insufficient privileges:

```
25.01.2021 10:13:00,689| INFO main [SYSTEM] creating user c##vdal ... |com.company.mpe.engine.SimpleScriptExecuter
25.01.2021 10:13:00,737| ERROR main Critical error occurred in [SYSTEM: grant select on all_sequences to c##vdal]:ORA-01031: Nicht ausreichende Berechtigungen
 |com.company.mpe.engine.SimpleScriptExecuter
25.01.2021 10:13:00,737| ERROR main Script stopped with errors. |com..mpe.engine.SimpleScriptExecuter
25.01.2021 10:13:00,745| ERROR main Error while executing buildDB, aborting the build |com.company.database.builddb.Build
com.company.mpe.engine.TaskExecutionException: Error occurred for task of type Case (at engine/params/mpe/mpeBuildDB.xml:360):Error in case-when construct: Error occurred for task of type Case (at engine/params/mpe/mpeBuildDB.xml:365):Error in case-when construct: Error occurred for task of type If (at engine/params/mpe/mpeBuildDB.xml:232):Error in if construction: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: Nicht ausreichende Berechtigungen
```

How can I configure the database so that I can successfully run all operations from outside like from my eclipse?

Comment: Give your user the DBA privilege.

Comment: which user and how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `DBA` rights to create or modify any user/schema in oracle.

You must be connecting with the database using some user. Let's say `userX`.

You can give the `DBA` privilege to `useX` from some DBA privileged user as follows:

```
grant dba to userx;
```

Beware that this will give all the system rights to `userX` and which is not recommended. This type of task should not be done from application.

Comment: I have successfully granted dba to the user *system* from sql developer. Still getting the same error msg.

Comment: dba user has all the rights to do anything. I think you should re-login to your database from java. try after bouncing your application server and make sure that you have given dba rights to the correct user.

Comment: "I have successfully granted dba to the user system"  That user already had DBA.